# Filtering a Web Service Data Control in JDeveloper

Tags: java, web-services, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have a web service data control in JDeveloper 12.2.1.3.0 which I show in a table on a page fragment, but I need to filter by one of the attributes and show the filtered data in the table and I don't know how to do that because there is no Named Criteria tab in the data control configuration page.

I looked at the data control configuration file but didn't find any option for adding a filter.

Any help will be really appreciate it, thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to call or implement a web service, that returns the data already sorted and/or filtered.

If this can't be done, you have to get the data from the web service in a POJO model and filter/sort it yourself.